# What $\frac{d}{dt}[F(\gamma(t))]$ where $F\in C^1(\Bbb R^n,\Bbb R^n)$ and $\gamma\in C^1(\Bbb R,\Bbb R^n)$?

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, partial-derivative

I know it's almost not worth your time but I'm struggling way too much with this simple derivative: $\frac{d}{dt}[F(\gamma(t))]$

$F=F(x_1,...,x_n)=(F^1(x_1,...,x_n),...,F^n(x_1,...,x_n))$

$\gamma=\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),...,\gamma_n(t))$, $t\in\Bbb R$

Notation: $\frac{\partial F^i(x)}{\partial x_j}\equiv F^i_{x_j}(x)$ and $\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}\equiv\gamma'(t)$

First let's calculate $\frac{d}{dt}F^i(\gamma(t))=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n F^i_{x_j}(\gamma_1(t),...,\gamma_n(t))\cdot\gamma_j'(t)=\langle \nabla F^i(\gamma(t)); \gamma'(t)\rangle$ where $\langle\ ;\ \rangle$ is the dot product.

Second $\frac{d}{dt}F(\gamma(t))=(\frac{d}{dt}F^1(\gamma(t)),...,\frac{d}{dt}F^n(\gamma(t)))=(\langle \nabla F^1(\gamma(t)); \gamma'(t)\rangle,...,\langle \nabla F^n(\gamma(t)); \gamma'(t)\rangle)$

Is that it?

Comment: Yes correct. We also write it $$J_F(\gamma (t))\dot\gamma (t),$$ where $J_F$ is the Jacobian of $F$.